# How can I simplify my stack of package managers?

Tags: package-managers, package-management

I don't know how it got this bad. I'm a web developer, and I use Ubuntu, and here are just some of the package managers I'm using.

- apt-get for system-wide packages
- npm for node packages
- pip for python packages
- pip3 for python 3 packages
- cabal for haskell packages
- composer for php packages
- bower for front-end packages
- gem for ruby packages
- git for other things

When I start a new project on a new VM, I have to install seemingly a dozen package managers from a dozen different places, and use them all to create a development environment. This is just getting out of control.

I've discovered that I can basically avoid installing and using pip/pip3 just by installing python packages from apt, like `sudo apt-get install python3-some-library`. This saves from having to use one package manager. That's awesome. But then I'm stuck with the Ubuntu versions of those packages, which are often really old.

What I'm wondering is, is there a meta-package manager that can help me to replace a few of these parts, so my dev environment is not so tricky to replicate?

Comment: Sorry I can't add anything useful to this, but: I feel you, brother.

Answer (score 1):

I had a thought to make a package manager to rule them all for that very reason. Never finished it though, too much effort required to stay compatible. For each package manager you have a huge community supporting it's upkeep.

Best advice I have is to try to reduce your toolchain for each type of project. Ideally you shouldn't need to work in every language you know for each project you work on. How many projects are you using that use both python 2 and python 3 simultaneously?

Keep using `apt` for your system packages and install `git` with it. From there try to stick to one language per project. AFAIK all of the package managers you listed support installing packages from `git`. The languages you mentioned all have comparable sets of tooling, so use the toolchain available for the target language.

I worked with a team that was using `composer`, `npm`, `bower`, `bundler`, `maven`, and a `tar.gz` file for frontend SPAs because those are the tools they knew. On top of all of that, they were using `vagrant` simply as a deployer. We considered our toolchain and described our need and realized that it could be expressed in a single language once we adopted appropriate tooling for the task at hand.